# Codeigniter Update not Executing as Expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm fairly new in programming, and I have a problem. I have a start billing button, which will make all user's monthly dues equal to 800. If I press it again, then the monthly dues will still be 800, but the arrears will now become 800. If I press it one last time, monthly dues will still be 800, then arrears will become 1600. The process goes on. My problem is that, I set up an if else in the model. If both the monthly dues and arrears is equal to 0, then it will properly update monthly dues to 800, and arrears will be still 0. However, if I change the values and make monthly dues and arrears to 0 in phpmyadmin (in order to simulate a homeowner paying his/her dues), the values follow others' accounts. Check the video below so that you can understand my point better.

Video: https://youtu.be/nULIAqLXNso

Model:

```
function billstart_user()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('accounts')->where('role', 0)->where('isActive', 1)->get();

    foreach($query->result() as $row):

        $data = array(
               'monthly_dues' => '800',
               'arrears' => '0',
            );

        $data2 = array(
               'monthly_dues' => '800',
               'arrears' => $row->arrears + '800'
            );


        if($row->arrears && $row->monthly_dues == 0)
        {
            $this->db->where('role', 0)->where('isActive', 1)->where('userid', $row->userid);
            $this->db->update('accounts',$data);

            print_r($this->db->last_query());
        }
        else if($row->arrears == 0 && $row->monthly_dues > 0 || $row->arrears && $row->monthly_dues > 0)
        {  
            $this->db->where('role', 0)->where('isActive', 1);
            $this->db->update('accounts',$data2); 

            print_r($this->db->last_query());
        }

    endforeach;
}
```

Here is what the query showed after updating:

```
UPDATE `accounts` SET `monthly_dues` = '800', `arrears` = '0' WHERE `role` =0 AND `isActive` = 1 AND `userid` = '32'
UPDATE `accounts` SET `monthly_dues` = '800', `arrears` = 4000 WHERE `role` =0 AND `isActive` = 1
UPDATE `accounts` SET `monthly_dues` = '800', `arrears` = 4000 WHERE `role` =0 AND `isActive` = 1
UPDATE `accounts` SET `monthly_dues` = '800', `arrears` = 4000 WHERE `role` =0 AND `isActive` = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying a `userid` only in the first query. That means the other 3 times the query runs you are applying `4000` to every single record in the table.

Comment: Wow I overlooked that! Thanks!

Comment: quick follow up, the rate I put in the model was 800. However, I also have an edit rate button in the website wherein I can change this rate, and the problem is that I hardcoded the 800 in the model. Should I create a database only for that rate?